# Apache Pig occurences of a character in descending order

Tags: apache-pig

I want to count the number of occurrences of a character in descending order/ascending order and neglecting special characters in `Apache Pig`? Can anyone give the solution for this?

My input file is like the following:

```
adaek@482;awst%16
alf$951;adftu*15
```

Desired output:

```
a : 5
d,t,f:2
e,k,w,l,u: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a UDF StringToCharArray that breaks a string into a bag of characters (wrap toCharArray() and return bag) and then do the following:

```
a = load ... as (inp : chararray);
b = foreach a generate flatten(StringToCharArray(inp)) as singlechar;
c = group b by singlechar;
d = foreach c generate c.group as singlechar, COUNT_STAR(b) as total;
e = group d by total;
f = foreach e generate d as chargroup, e.group as total;
dump f;
```